# How to change the layout on button click based on the radio button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-sdk-2.3

I want to change the activity when button clicked and new layout will be opened based on which radio button is checked.I have three radio button .I want to change the layout based on the checked radio button and next button click .Here is my code

```
    package com.edkul.vimal.edkul;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class Join_AS_A extends AppCompatActivity {

        private RadioGroup radioGroup;
        private RadioButton radioButton;
        private Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_join__as_);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            radioGroup  = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.joinGroup);
            radioGroup.clearCheck();
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String selection = (String) radioButton.getText();
                    Log.i("Print here", selection);
                    if (selection.equals("Student") && view ==btn){
                        Intent intentMain = new Intent(Join_AS_A.this, Student_Signup.class);
                        Join_AS_A.this.startActivity(intentMain);
                        Log.i("Content ", " Main layout ");
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Here is the xml code

Here is the xml file :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.edkul.vimal.edkul.Join_AS_A"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_join__as_">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/joinAsA"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:id="@+id/joinGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/joinasaStudent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/joinasaTeacher"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/joinasaparent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:checked="false" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/joinNext"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/joinGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the code of on click is something like:-

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.joinGroup);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (selectedId == R.id.radioButton) {
                Intent intentMain = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Student_Signup.class);
                startActivity(intentMain);
                Log.i("Content ", " Main layout ");
            }

        }
    });
```

As you are getting the checked radio button id in oncreate() so its reference will not gets change even if user will select some other radio button. So you have to find the selected radio button id when user will click on next button and then have to perform operation accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have copied same code over mine.But still not able to change the layout.sorry.

Comment: I am not seeing any error ..and even my log statements are not printing...can you please suggest how to check the error ..sorry i am very new to android this is my first app

Comment: can you please edit the question and post your xml? It will be helpful to identify the issue

Comment: int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (selectedId==R.id.radioButton){
            Intent intentMain = new Intent(Join_AS_A.this,Student_Signup.class);
            Join_AS_A.this.startActivity(intentMain);
            Log.i("Content ", " Main layout ");
           }

Comment: Please change the onclick method code by this. It will work.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.edkul.vimal.edkul, PID: 18062
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.edkul.vimal.edkul.Join_AS_A$2.onClick(Join_AS_A.java:49)

Comment: I am getting error in this line  int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
Any suggestion please.